# How do i solve this error: 'Frame' does not exist in the current context'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

Here is my script for light estimation testing, how do i solve this error: **'Frame does not exist in the current context'**. When I replace GoogleARCore with XR.ARfoundation i get that error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;

public class LightEstimationTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Range(0f,1f)]
    public float testValue = 0.5F;
    
    void OnValidate()
    {
        setGlobalLightEstimation(testValue);
    }
        
    void setGlobalLightEstimation(float lightValue)
    {
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_GlobalLightEstimation", lightValue);
    }
    
    
    void Update()
    {
        setGlobalLightEstimation(Frame.LightEstimate.PixelIntensity); 
    }

}
```

Comment: well what is `Frame` and where dos it come from?

Comment: Not an expert on the topic, but from my quick research, `Frame` is GoogleARCore class, so if you switch to Unity's XR.ARFoundation there is no such thing - you need to rewrite your logic. Read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.1/manual/index.html).